# how to use unicode character in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode

For a js click function to View and Hide some comments, i use this unicode
`&#9660;` and `&#9650;` (Arrow up and arrow down)

```
$('.toggle-<?php echo $comment_id; ?>').click(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Hide replies &#9650;' ? 'View replies &#9660;' : 'Hide replies &#9650;');
```

But it shows me literally the code instead of the arrow.

So how i need to use the code in the script above?

Comment: Why not directly use `"View replies ▼"`?

Comment: I did, but when i toggle, the text must change to "Hide replies arrow" and click again, change to "View replies arrow" again

Comment: Yes, I'm asking why not use the condition `$(this).text() == 'View replies ▼'` in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `&#<num>;` is html, therefore it needs to be entered as such, using `$(...).html('&#9660 ...')` instead of `$(...).text('&#9660 ...')`.

The following should work:

```
$(this).html($(this).text().substr(0,4) == 'Hide' ? 'View replies &#9660;' : 'Hide replies &#9650;');
```

Comment: Agree! Works great now. Thnx